# JOIN query using SignalR and SqlDependency in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, sql-server, asp.net-core, signalr

In my project, I use SignalR and SqlDependency. There is no problem when I use a normal SELECT query or a parameterized query. But when I create a query with JOIN, I get an error.

Repository,

```
    public List<ResultNotificationDto> ListNotification(int id)
    {
        var notificationDtos = new List<ResultNotificationDto>();

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string query = "SELECT N.LogID, U.Name + ' ' + U.Surname AS SenderUserID, N.RecordID, N.Timestamp, N.Description, N.Title, N.NotificationIcon FROM Notification N INNER JOIN AspNetUsers U ON N.SenderUserID = U.Id WHERE N.Status = 0 AND N.ReceiverUserID = @receiverUserID";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@receiverUserID", id);
            var dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dbChangeNotification);
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var notificationDto = new ResultNotificationDto
                {
                    LogID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["LogID"]),
                    SenderUserID = reader["SenderUserID"].ToString(),
                    Action = reader["Action"].ToString(),
                    TableName = reader["TableName"].ToString(),
                    RecordID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["RecordID"]),
                    Timestamp = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Timestamp"]),
                    Description = reader["Description"].ToString(),
                    Title = reader["Title"].ToString(),
                    NotificationIcon = reader["NotificationIcon"].ToString(),
                };
                notificationDtos.Add(notificationDto);
            }
        }
        return notificationDtos;
    }

    private void dbChangeNotification(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveNotification");
    }
```

Index.cshtml,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/appHub").build();
        connection.start();

        connection.on("ReceiveNotification", function () {
            loadData()
        });

        loadData();

        function loadData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/Home/GetIndex",
                success: function (value) {
                    $("#tableExpense tbody").empty();

                    var tablerow;
                    $.each(value, (index, item) => {
                        tablerow = $("<tr/>");
                        tablerow.append(`<td><a class="fw-semibold text-primary">#${item.logID}</a></td>`)
                        tablerow.append(`<td>${item.senderUserID}</td>`)
                        tablerow.append(`<td>${item.action}</td>`)
                        tablerow.append(`<td>${item.tableName}</td>`)
                        tablerow.append(`<td>${item.recordID}</td>`);
                        tablerow.append(`<td>${item.timeStamp}</td>`);
                        tablerow.append(`<td>${item.description}</td>`);
                        tablerow.append(`<td>${item.title}</td>`);
                        tablerow.append(`<td>${item.notificationIcon}</td>`);
                        $("#tableExpense").append(tablerow);
                    })
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                }
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

HomeController.cs,

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetIndex()
{
    var findUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
    int id = findUser.Id;
    return Ok(_notificationDal.ListNotification(id));
}
```

GET https://localhost:7243/Home/GetIndex 500 (Internal Server Error)

I get this error in the console.

Comment: What's the real error you're getting?

Comment: `SqlDependency` is built-on Query Notifications, which in-turn [places restrictions on your queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms181122(v=sql.105)) - though `INNER JOIN` should be permitted (as per the doc: it isn't on the not-supported-list) but methinks it's a good idea to avoid any kind of non-trivial queries.

Comment: Also, you _really_ should update your query to use schema-qualified identifiers - otherwise you'll run into problems (both correctness _and_ performance-related).

Comment: Normally I can run this query with dapper. But SqlDependency is not used with Dapper. That's why I need to write this JOIN query, but it also gives an error.

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints and stepping through your code? I'd imagine there are exceptions when attempting to execute `reader["Action"].ToString()` and `reader["TableName"].ToString()`. Have you tried including `Action` and `TableName` columns in your query?

Comment: Aside... you should specify correct data types and length/precision/scale when adding parameters to `SqlCommand`s. [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) ...and... [AddWithValue is Evil.](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)